# adding tooltips to google visualization bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to add custom tooltips to a Google Bar Chart, but I can't figure out how to do this.
Google provides a nice tutorial (at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content), but it only discusses ColumnCharts, rather than Bar Charts.

Here's what my code looks like:

```html
<div id="top_x_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

```js
google.load("visualization", "1.1",{packages:["bar"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff0);

function drawStuff0() {
   var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([$data]);
   var options = {
       title: 'Categories',
       width: 900,
       legend: { position: 'none' },
       chart: { title: 'popularity by number of queries',
                subtitle: 'Number of times a category was queried' },
       bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
       axes: {
                x: {
                    0: { side: 'top', label: 'Number of times a category was queried'} // Top x-axis.
                }
             },
       bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
   };

   var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div0'));

   // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
   chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

`$data` is simply a PHP variable containing the rows of the chart.

Could someone explain how to add a custom tooltip to this chart?
I've looked all over the web for a solution, I haven't been able to find one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new column to the DataTable object with the role `tooltip` :

```js
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
```

Then loop through `data` and add whatever tooltip you want (example from the one column bar chart fiddle below) for each row :

```js
for (var i=0; i<data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
   data.setValue(i, 2, 'Tooltip #'+i);
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pc3zmb8w/**

I cannot guide you more exactly since we dont know what your PHP `$data` is or how your chart looks like. But this is basically how you should do it, in all cases, when you want to add custom tooltips to a chart dynamically ...

---

**Update** - styling the tooltip

As for "*is there a way to have the tool-tips appear as a rectangle, rather than a speech blurb*", in the options - set `tooltip` as `isHtml` :

```js
var options = {
    tooltip: {isHtml: true} 
}
```

Then the tooltip appears as a rectangle like normal HTML-element tooltips. You can also specify that you want to use HTML inside the tooltip itself :

```js
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {'html': true}});
```

For example to show the tooltip with the colors of a normal tooltip, but using a larger fontsize and a certain font :

```css
div.tooltip {
    background-color: #ffffca;
    color: #000023;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family : 'arial';
}
```

Set the tooltip as in original answer :

```js
data.setValue(i, 2, '<div class="tooltip">Tooltip #'+i+'</div>');
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yhhhcj2f/**

Comment: Thanks so much for the example, it was very helpful! Here's a picture of what I wanted my chart to look like: http://i61.tinypic.com/9hn9m0.jpg. Do you know how to retain the "look" of that chart (font, sizing, etc), while adding in the code that you provided? Also, is there a way to have the tool-tips appear as a rectangle, rather than a speech blurb?

Comment: @JMS, there is no image in your link

Comment: @JMS, it was perhaps a cache problem on that imageserver. I cannot tell what font, sizes, colors etc is by looking at an image. It looks like completely standard to me, and has BTW not very much to do with tooltips :)  But I can tell how you can get rectangle tooltips with google visualization and how to style them, see update.

Comment: Great answer, I really appreciate it